# NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of Landroid/support/v4/util/ArrayMap at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp

Tags: android, firebase

Using Android Studio version 3.5 I am getting following error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of  Landroid/support/v4/util/ArrayMap at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.(Unknown Source)

```
    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
        implementation files('libs/mpchartlib.jar')
        implementation files('libs/sun.misc.BASE64Decoder.jar')
        implementation files('libs/NineOldAndroid-2.4.0.jar')
        implementation files('libs/AndroidEasingFunctions-1.0.0.jar')
        implementation files('libs/AndroidViewAnimations-1.1.3.jar')
        implementation files('libs/android-async-http-1.4.4.jar')
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.6.0'
        implementation files('libs/jackson-all-1.9.0.jar')
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.0'
        implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
        implementation files('libs/commons-codec-1.9.jar')
        implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
        implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:29.0.1'
       implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    }
```

Comment: Improved formatting and title.

Comment: @help-info.de nice good job!